# Upgraded to Magento 2.0.14 now many of my pages lost their formatting

Tags: magento2

Ubuntu 14.04
Magento 2.0.14

I'm not sure how to call this, but my pages are losing their format after recently completing an update from Magento 2.0.7 to 2.0.14. I updated Magento through the command line. I got no errors during the process. Some pages work (like the home page) and others don't (like the customer and admin logins). Other times it works fine once and then the formatting is gone when I reload the page.

I tried clearing the cache, but since there's no error message I don't even know where to start looking. The pages are still functional; it's just a problem with the formatting.

[image: The admin panel login is messed up.]

[image: This is another example from the customer login.]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to make sure you did production deploy correct.

Try to run this command.

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable &&
php bin/magento cache:disable &&
php bin/magento setup:upgrade &&
php bin/magento setup:di:compile &&
php bin/magento indexer:reindex &&
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy &&
php bin/magento cache:clean &&
php bin/magento cache:flush &&
php bin/magento cache:enable &&
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```